# Search for div classes with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, class, html

Sounds simple, huh. Lot's of answers i found but all use jQuery or ProtoType. I want plain JavaScript. It shouldn't be that hard, but JavaScript is not my thing; no central documentation means searching for ages and not finding what i want.

Consider the following HTML code snippet:

```
<div class="central_0"> .. </div>
<div class="central_1"> .. </div>
<div class="central_2"> .. </div>
```

Now I want to use JavaScript to do things with those DIVs.

```
function processDivElements()
{
 // search for relevant DIV classes
 var divArray = document.getElementsByClass.regex('/^central_.*$/');

 // do stuff with the DIV elements found
 foreach (divArray as divElement)
 {
   divElement.style.background = '#f00';
 };
}
```

Can anyone help me translate this to proper **plain** JavaScript? I use classes, not IDs. I prefer using a regular expression.

Comment: To be fair, some people don't want/need to load an entire library for one function.

Comment: Although is true that there aren't many "official" JS materials, you can get started pretty quickly at the MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript. It has great JS documentation.

Comment: @Zeb - it's just a matter of how much his time is worth, and how much the 32K or so jQuery uses is worth.  My money's on the developer's time being the more valuable quantity there.

Comment: I would strongly recommend not using jQuery unless you plan to take advantage of most of what it offers. To use it for something such as this is a bit ridiculous when only 100 or so byte will be used of the 32k that comprises it.

Comment: @SReject: If you load jQuery from Google's CDN, there's a really good chance that the user's browser will load it from cache.

Comment: 1: 'a good chance' doesn't mean it will. Also, jquerys size in file is one thing, but it grows as it is inturpeted by the js engine. 2: CDN askes for devs not to link to their repositories, but rather host the file(s) on your own server

Comment: I think the thing to remember here is that a developer's time, and more maintainable code are both infinitely more valuable/important than 32K of bandwidth.  Maybe this is the only jQuery thing he needs *now*, until he wants delegated events, then to toggle the visibility of an element, then to fade an element out, etc

Comment: @SReject: The whole point of a CDN is to leverage browser caching. You're encouraged to load jQuery and other libraries from a CDN to save bandwidth.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The jQuery solution is really nice:

```
var $divs = $('div[class^="central_"]');
```

If you only want to support newer browsers, you can use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.querySelectorAll) to do essentially the same thing:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[class^="central_"]');
```

If you want to support older browsers, the code gets horrible:

```
var all_divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var divs = [];

for (var i = 0; i < all_divs.length; i++) {
    var div = all_divs[i];

    if (div.className.match(/^central_\d+$/) {
        divs.push(div);
    }
}
```

Also:

> I use classes, not IDs. I prefer using a regular expression.

Your classes are unique and are really functioning like IDs, which isn't really the intended use of classes. Structure your HTML like this instead:

```
<div id="central_0" class="central">...</div>
<div id="central_1" class="central">...</div>
<div id="central_2" class="central">...</div>
```

Now, the JavaScript becomes simpler:

```
var $divs = $('.central');                               // jQuery
var divs =  document.querySelectorAll('.central');       // Newer browsers
var divs =  document.getElementsByClassName('central');  // Older browsers
```

Comment: afaik jQ actually calls `document.querySelectorAll` if the browser supports it

Comment: @TwiNight: Yep. `querySelectorAll` is faster than traversing the DOM using JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir!

However, i have several reasons for NOT wanting to use external libraries like jQuery. I would prefer the 'horrible' Javascript solution over a library solution any day.

Also, your suggestion of using IDs rather than classes is understandable. However, please be aware that my question is extremely simplified. The DIVs in question already have an ID used for different purpose, and as far as i know only **ONE** ID is allowed. That is why i must use classes instead. I will report back on whether your traditional solution works for me. Thank you again!

Comment: I know it's 10hrs old, but you could use the name attribute inplace of id's. and use `.getElementsByName("nameAttribute")`

Answer (score 2):

As the others have mentioned you can't directly support a regex select on the `getElementsByClassName` method call.

But I will point out these other issues with your code, since you are new to javascript.

Using classes is fine, but your making more work for yourself by writing up your html like that.

Instead of the `central_0....central_2` if they are all basically operating on the same css rules, you should write them like this `central zero....central two` then your `central` class can have identical rules, while you can assign any differences to the `#` classes. This way your also adhering to the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Also you should really consider sticking to the best practices for the language. If your not assigning css rules to your elements with those classes then you should be using `id's`, plus it makes your life much easier.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get the matched elements by regex directly, the only thing you could do is to get all the elements by something (like: TagName, Name, etc..) and then filter the elements by regex.

With your html sample, you could only get all the element by TagName, and use regex to check the `className` by regex.

Answer (score 0):

One quicker way to do so is to create a simple `<style>` as follows:

```
<style>
    div[class^="central_"] {
        background-color: #f00;
    }
</style>
```

Therefore, as you look for **plain javascript**, useless to say that you can add `<style>` tags at will, by using javascript. A whole HTML example as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class= "central_1">
        central 1
    </div>

    <script>
        var css = "<style>div[class^=\"central_\"] {background-color: #f00;}</style>";
        var list = document.querySelector("head"); list.innerHTML += css;
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```