# JavaScript how to find a class that is constantly changing

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

Example: the class was `Paragraph__P2Short--18r8zx8 styles__DateUpdated--7vi2vd kYkeUS` after an hour it changed to `Paragraph__P2Short--vgyzhi styles__DateUpdated--6ztczv fQPIAt`. How do I find such classes?

I tried `document.getElementsByClassName("")` but the class is constantly changing, but the `styles__DateUpdated` does not change in the class

Comment: The website designer likely dynamically generates the name to prevent people from doing what you are trying to do. However, there are ways to still reliably access the element based on it's location within the HTML markup. In particular, you could try XPATH or the children of another element or class that isn't changing. Look at the HTML hierarchy and figure out what _isn't changing_ and then you can identify the element you are looking for. If `styles__DateUpdated` is always in the classname, you could use a regex. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775282/search-for-div-classes-with-regex

Comment: Who or what is updating the class name?

Comment: @h0r53 that looks like its standard output from a CSS module compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try a CSS selector with `.querySelectorAll`, like:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('[class*="styles__DateUpdated--"]');
```

It will givve you all elements containing the string "styles__DateUpdated--" inside the class attribute. For sure you might have to go deeper to filter down to what you need...